# Finding the sum of prime Numbers in a List in Python

Tags: loops, python-3.x, math

I am Trying this question as an exercise but i am stuck.I will try to be as precise as possible

I would like to find the sum of primes with the list as an input

Say the input given to my function is a list like=[17,51,29,39],so it should return 46 as the answer as 17+29=46

Here's the code what i could write:

```
def sumprimes(l):
    sum=0
    for value in l:
        for i in range(1,float((value)/2)):
            if value%i==0:
                      sum+=value     
    print(sum)
```

Note-on passing a list,the program should work. I haven't written this part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not start with making a separate function `def is_prime(n)` which tells whether one number is prime or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better create a function to test if number is prime as @wim said.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    elif n <= 3:
        return True
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    # round up the sqrt of n
    length = int(n**.5) + 1  # n**.5 is equal to sqrt(n)
    for i in range(3, length, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

This is a simple and efficient primality test.
Then you can simply sum with:

```
def sum_primes(l):
    return sum(n for n in l if is_prime(n))
```

Comment: You could make this more efficient. `class IsPrime:;
  def __init__(self):;
    self.prime_set = set([2]);
  def is_prime(self, n);
    if n in self.prime_set: return true;
    # 2 is always in the set, so any even number that gets here is non prime;
    if not n%2: return false;
    length = int(n**.5) + 1  # n**.5 is equal to sqrt(n);
    for i in range(3, length, 2):;
        if n % i == 0:;
            return False;
    self.prime_set.add(n);
    return True;` this is a simple addition of a set to store the previously found primes. this saves the hassle of re-generating them.

Comment: An alternate method would be to generate all the primes up to the value.  This allows for two further optimisations: 1) if the value is not in the set but there is a value in the set greater than it, then it is not prime. 2) for values greater than the largest prime, you only have to test against known primes not all odd numbers up to that value.  This would be less efficient for a single call, but would be far more eficcient over many calls to is_prime() as posed by the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using `range` with  float value. 
What you really need here is integer division. In Python 3, that is the `//` operator:

```
def sum_primes(l):
    total = 0
    for value in l:
        for i in range(2, value // 2):
            if value%i == 0:
                break
        else:
            total += value     
    return total
```

Also, you need to check if value is divisible by every number except 1 and itself. All numbers will be divisible by 1. So start the range from 2. Furthermore, it is numbers that are divisible that aren't prime, so add an else clause to your for-loop which is only executed if your for-loop goes to completion without the breaking i.e. none of the numbers you checked divide value, thus value is prime!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your queries

```
def sumprimes(l):
primeNum = []
for item in l:
    is_prime = True
    if(item >= 2):
        maxInt = int(item ** 0.5) + 1
        for i in range(2, maxInt):
            if(item % i == 0):
                is_prime = False
                break
        if(is_prime):
            primeNum.append(item)
return(sum(primeNum))

print(function([-3,1,6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumprime(list):
    sum =0
    flag =1
    for i in range(len(list)):
        num = list[i]
        for j in range(2, num):
            if list[i]%j ==0:
                flag = 0
                break
            else:
                flag = 1
        if num ==2:
            flag =1
        if flag ==1:
            sum =sum +list[i]
    return(sum)

list =[2,3,5,7]
print(sumprime(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime(n):
    count = 0
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            if n % i == 0:
                count = count + 1        
        if count == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def sumprimes(l):
    x = list(filter(prime,l))
    y = sum(x)
    return y
print(sumprimes([-3,3,1,13]))
```

Comment: For a given list partition the list based on prime(n) by using filter function and apply sum() function to add all the elements in the new list.